# lang/expect: execute a different binary if the prior one doesn't exist

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, tcl, expect

I'm using [lang/expect](http://ports.su/lang/expect), and for the `spawn` command, I'd like to conditionally execute one of two different binaries, e.g., depending on whether or not `qemu-system-x86_64` exists, I'd like to either do a `spawn qemu-system-x86_64 …`, or, if it doesn't exist, simply call `spawn kvm …` instead.  (The arguments to both `kvm` and `qemu-…` commands are the same, only the name of the executable itself is different.)

How do I do it within the Expect language?

Per the [documentation of how the `spawn` directive within `expect`](http://mdoc.su/f/expect.1) works (it internally does a [`fork`](http://mdoc.su/f/fork.2)), one "recommended" approach would be to see if the execution fails by looking at what the spawned process prints to its terminal; however, that would be suboptimal, as I simply want to test whether the given executable exists (in `$PATH`).

Comment: @pynexj you don't really have to delete the post, i was just making sure it all works before accept etc.

Comment: @pynexj btw, once you reach 10k, you can still see deleted answers, in case you meant to delete for me to no longer see the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Tcl command `auto_execok cmd`, which returns the full path to `cmd` (with respect to the `PATH` environment variable), or an empty string if `cmd` cannot be found.
See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/library.htm#M6 for details.

```
if {[auto_execok qemu-system-x86_64] != {}} {
    # qemu-system-x86_64 is found in the path. spawn it...
    spawn qemu-system-x86_64 
} else {
    # fall back to kvm
    spawn kvm
}
```

Comment: If you're dealing with local executables, that works fine.